# autocomplete settings, IDE or text editor, writting plugin

Tags: java, text, plugins, ide, editor

I have an kinda difficult question(btw, sorry for my english).

My mad boss wants me to wrote a lot of strange text (i cant call it code), the problem is in the autocomplete, i will try to explain:

For example I am need to write text, about 120 000 words, and some sentences uses in this text really often - about 100 times, this sentences is "QuIcK brOwn foX", "jums over something" and "i dont know english" (case is important, also there actually about 200 sentences, which uses 100 times and some of them starts with quotes), so i hope there is some text editor or IDE which will give me an opportunity to customize autocomplete settings to make this job easier, but i dint found any one... If u know some software, which will help me, i will bw very Thankful

BTW, if u know, where i can find detail information about writting autocomplete plugins for any text editor or IDE, i also will be very thankful!

i probaly wasnt very clear, actually i have a lot of java classes, which contains only fields whit annotantions like:

@NameOfField("dat brown fox")
Enimal datBrownFox;

@NameOfField("dat Lazy Dog")
Enimal datLazyDog;

And i have to write some code in... TXT file, which looks like BDD scenario:

"dat Lazy Dog" bites "dat brown fox"

And it must be absolutelly the same as text in the annotaions, in other way it does not work fine, and dint throwing any error...

There are may be about 1000 this annotations in all project in different classes, different packages etc.

Comment: Most editors and IDEs have a feature called "snippets" or (in case of IntelliJ IDEA) "live templates" which can be used for this. You don't need to write a plugin.

Comment: Snippets and live templates also work in TXT files.

Comment: update description

Comment: i actually can parse all java classe to find all of them and write it to.. emm.. txt file why not, but how to add a 1000 live templates? manually? god dam legacy code...

Comment: thank you for advise, i find out  where life template xml file is, its not a problem anymore))

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated, but I think **Netbeans** does what you're asking.

Go to **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Editor** tab -> **Code Templates** tab

Then click "**New**" on the right side, and for the abbreviation use the first letter (or two, or three) of the sentence you want to auto-complete. Fill in the full sentence under "**Expanded Text**," and set "**Expand Template on:**" to "**Tab**" (or whatever key you'd prefer). Click **OK**.

Now when you type the first letter of the sentence and press **Tab**, it should auto-complete that sentence.